# Remove click event with JQuery on / off call not working?

Tags: jquery, ajax

FINAL UPDATE

I know have it working (or at lest all the tests I have done so far work)

This is how I have set it up, not sure if its right or wrong. :) I will mark your answer as right, because I would not have done anything like this, if it was not for your help. Many thanks.

```
var CommentClick = function() {
    $('.ReadMore').on('click', function() { 
        var CommentID = $(this).attr('id');
        FoundComment(CommentID); 
        $( ".ReadMore" ).off( "click");
    }); 
}

var FoundComment = function(JsonComment){
    var RequestedID = JsonComment;
    var CommentRequest = $.ajax({
        url: '/feedback',
        data: { CommentID: RequestedID },
        type: "POST",
        success: function(reply) {
            CommentData(reply); //Send JSON data to function for display
        } //End of success callback   
    }); //End of AJAX
}

var CommentData = function(SeletedComment) {
    var JsonData = $.parseJSON(SeletedComment); //Parse requested JSON data

    //Each needed data asigned to its own var
    var Comment = JsonData.Comment; 
    var Stars = JsonData.Stars;
    var User = JsonData.User;

    $('.FeedBackCommentFull').html('<span class="CloseComment shadow raised">CLOSE ME</span>');
    $('.FeedBackCommentFull').append('<div><span id="FeedBackUser">User: '+User+'</span> <span id="FeedBackStars"></span></div>');
    $('.FeedBackCommentFull').append('<span id="FeedBackComment">'+Comment+'</span>');
    $('.FeedBackCommentFull').slideToggle(700,"easeOutBounce");

    $('#FeedBackStars').raty({
        size: 16,
        path: 'assets/imgs/raty',
        score: Stars,               
        readOnly: true
    });

    $(' .CloseComment ').click(function() {
        $('.FeedBackCommentFull').slideToggle(700,"easeOutBounce");
        $( ".ReadMore" ).on("click", CommentClick() );   

    });
}

CommentClick();
```

---

UPDATE 3

This is my current code :

```
 var DisplayMyComments = function(){
    var self = this;

    this.validCommentRequest = false;
    this.CommentRequest = {done : false};
    // Your clickhandler, named 'test' before
    this.clickHandler = function(event){
        var RequestedID = $(this).attr('id'); //Get ID of clicked div tag
        self.CommentRequest = $.ajax({
            url: '/feedback',
            data: { CommentID: RequestedID },
            type: "POST",
            success: function(reply) {
                self.validCommentRequest = true;
                var JsonData = $.parseJSON(reply); //Parse requested JSON data

                //Each needed data asigned to its own var
                var Comment = JsonData.Comment; 
                var Stars = JsonData.Stars;
                var User = JsonData.User;

                $('.FeedBackCommentFull').html('<span class="CloseComment shadow raised">CLOSE ME</span>');
                $('.FeedBackCommentFull').append('<div><span id="FeedBackUser">User: '+User+'</span> <span id="FeedBackStars"></span></div>');
                $('.FeedBackCommentFull').append('<span id="FeedBackComment">'+Comment+'</span>');
                $('.FeedBackCommentFull').slideToggle(700,"easeOutBounce");

                $('#FeedBackStars').raty({
                    size: 16,
                    path: 'assets/imgs/raty',
                    score: Stars,               
                    readOnly: true
                });

            } //End of success callback   
        });
    }

    $('.ReadMore').on('click', self.clickHandler);

    $.when(self.CommentRequest).done(function() {
        if(!self.validCommentRequest)return;
        if ($('.FeedBackCommentFull').is(':visible')) {
            $('.ReadMore').off('click', self.clickHandler);
            console.log( 'test...off' );
        }

        $(' .CloseComment ').click(function() {
            $('.FeedBackCommentFull').slideToggle(700,"easeOutBounce");
            $('.ReadMore').on('click', self.clickHandler);
            console.log( 'test...on' );
        });
    }); //End of When       
}
DisplayMyComments();
```

---

UPDATE 2

This is what I am currently using,

```
var DisplayMyComments = function(){
    var self = this;
    //var CommentRequest; <- try this, did not seem to change the error
    this.CommentRequest = {done : false};
    // Your clickhandler, named 'test' before
    this.clickHandler = function(event){
                    var RequestedID = $(this).attr('id'); //Get ID of clicked div tag
        self.CommentRequest = $.ajax({
            url: '/feedback',
            data: { CommentID: RequestedID },
            type: "POST",
            success: function(reply) {
                var JsonData = $.parseJSON(reply); //Parse requested JSON data

                //Each needed data asigned to its own var
                var Comment = JsonData.Comment; 
                var Stars = JsonData.Stars;
                var User = JsonData.User;

                $('.FeedBackCommentFull').html('<span class="CloseComment shadow raised">CLOSE ME</span>');
                $('.FeedBackCommentFull').append('<div><span id="FeedBackUser">User: '+User+'</span> <span id="FeedBackStars"></span></div>');
                $('.FeedBackCommentFull').append('<span id="FeedBackComment">'+Comment+'</span>');
                $('.FeedBackCommentFull').slideToggle(700,"easeOutBounce");

                $('#FeedBackStars').raty({
                    size: 16,
                    path: 'assets/imgs/raty',
                    score: Stars,               
                    readOnly: true
                });

            } //End of success callback   
        });
    }

    $('.ReadMore').on('click', self.clickHandler);

    $.when(self.CommentRequest).done(function() {
        if ($('.FeedBackCommentFull').is(':visible')) {
            $('.ReadMore').off('click', self.clickHandler);
            console.log( 'test...off' );
        }

        $(' .CloseComment ').click(function() {
            $('.FeedBackCommentFull').slideToggle(700,"easeOutBounce");
            $('.ReadMore').on('click', self.clickHandler);
            console.log( 'test...on' );
        });
    }); //End of When       
}
DisplayMyComments();
```

Many, many thanks for the help you are giving me. :)

---

UPDATE :

This is what I did, but for some reason nothing happens when the button is click?

```
      var DisplayMyComments = function() { 
    var self = this;

    $('.ReadMore').on('click', self.clickHandler);

    this.clickhandler = $('.ReadMore').on('click', function(event) {
        var RequestedID = $(this).attr('id'); //Get ID of clicked div tag
    });

        this.CommentRequest = $.ajax({
            url: '/feedback',
            data: { CommentID: RequestedID },
            type: "POST",
            success: function(reply) {
                var JsonData = $.parseJSON(reply); //Parse requested JSON data

                //Each needed data asigned to its own var
                var Comment = JsonData.Comment; 
                var Stars = JsonData.Stars;
                var User = JsonData.User;

                $('.FeedBackCommentFull').html('<span class="CloseComment shadow raised">CLOSE ME</span>');
                $('.FeedBackCommentFull').append('<div><span id="FeedBackUser">User: '+User+'</span> <span id="FeedBackStars"></span></div>');
                $('.FeedBackCommentFull').append('<span id="FeedBackComment">'+Comment+'</span>');
                $('.FeedBackCommentFull').slideToggle(700,"easeOutBounce");

                $('#FeedBackStars').raty({
                    size: 16,
                    path: 'assets/imgs/raty',
                    score: Stars,               
                    readOnly: true
                });

            } //End of success callback   
        }); //End of AJAX request for User Comment


        //When AJAX request is complete / done, load click event for close button
        $.when (self.CommentRequest).done(function() {
            if ($('.FeedBackCommentFull').is(':visible')) {
                $('.ReadMore').off('click', self.clickHandler);
                //$('body').off('click', '.ReadMore', test);
                ///$('.ReadMore').css("visibility","hidden");
                //console.log( 'test...off' );
            }

            $(' .CloseComment ').click(function() {
                $('.FeedBackCommentFull').slideToggle(700,"easeOutBounce");
                $('.ReadMore').on('click', self.clickHandler);
                //$('body').on('click', '.ReadMore', test);
                //console.log( 'test...on' );
                //$('.ReadMore').css("visibility","visible");
            });
        }); //End of When

    //}); //End of on click for ReadMore link

} //End of function
```

I have a fully (well almost) working bit of JQuery code. I am building a comments section to my site that loads / slides a div tag into view with AJAX loaded data, once a 'Read More' button (div tag) is click.,=

The problem I am having is with my on / off calls with the click button that loads this code. Because my site is RWD built, the container element will at some point show the 'read more' button that loads this div. So what I am trying to do, is when the AJAX content div is vistable, to remove the click event to my 'read more' button with 'off'.

Here is my whole code section,

```
 $('.ReadMore').on('click', function(event) {

    var RequestedID = $(this).attr('id'); //Get ID of clicked div tag
    var CommentRequest = $.ajax({
        url: '/getusercomments',
        data: { CommentID: RequestedID },
        type: "POST",
        success: function(reply) {
            var JsonData = $.parseJSON(reply); //Parse requested JSON data

            //Each needed data asigned to its own var
            var Comment = JsonData.Comment; 
            var Stars = JsonData.Stars;
            var User = JsonData.User;

            $('.FeedBackCommentFull').html('<span class="CloseComment shadow raised">CLOSE ME</span>');
            $('.FeedBackCommentFull').append('<div><span id="FeedBackUser">User: '+User+'</span> <span id="FeedBackStars"></span></div>');
            $('.FeedBackCommentFull').append('<span id="FeedBackComment">'+Comment+'</span>');
            $('.FeedBackCommentFull').slideToggle(700,"easeOutBounce");

            $('#FeedBackStars').raty({
                size: 16,
                path: 'assets/imgs/raty',
                score: Stars,               
                readOnly: true
            });

        } //End of success callback   
    }); //End of AJAX request for User Comment

    //When AJAX request is complete / done, load click event for close button
    $.when (CommentRequest).done(function() {
        if ($('.FeedBackCommentFull').is(':visible')) {
            $('.ReadMore').off('click');
            console.log( 'test...off' );
        }

        $(' .CloseComment ').click(function() {
            $('.FeedBackCommentFull').slideToggle(700,"easeOutBounce");
            $('.ReadMore').on('click');
            console.log( 'test...on' );
        });
    }); //End of When

}); //End of on click for ReadMore link
```

The URL I get the data from uses PHP Slim to get a list of all comments submitted and JSON encodes this data, what I sort and display out. this all works, it even removes the 'click' event from the 'Read More' button but for some reason it does not add back the click event one the 'close' button is selected.

Now I have also tried, putting the 'Read More' click into a var and then calling it, like so,

```
   var test = $('.ReadMore').on('click', function(event) { .......
```

Then trying to load it in like so,

```
    $.when (CommentRequest).done(function() {
        if ($('.FeedBackCommentFull').is(':visible')) {
            $('.ReadMore').off('click', test);
            console.log( 'test...off' );
        }

        $(' .CloseComment ').click(function() {
            $('.FeedBackCommentFull').slideToggle(700,"easeOutBounce");
            $('.ReadMore').on('click', test);
            console.log( 'test...on' );
        });
    }); //End of When
```

But when I do this, it does not remove the click event and I get  `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

I have also tried assigning the on/off to the body, like,

```
                    if ($('.FeedBackCommentFull').is(':visible')) {
            $('body').off('click', '.ReadMore', test);
            console.log( 'test...off' );
        }

        $(' .CloseComment ').click(function() {
            $('.FeedBackCommentFull').slideToggle(700,"easeOutBounce");
            $('body').on('click', '.ReadMore', test);
            console.log( 'test...on' );
        });
```

With the same effect as the test before, so what am I doing wrong?

All help very welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: in your context it seems that "test" is "undefined" it means that when you do this "$('body').off('click', '.ReadMore', test);" test does not exist

Comment: when I read the doc "test" should just be a function and not a binding http://api.jquery.com/off/

Comment: For the first point I made you have to answer this where do you set "test" variable ?

Comment: @Su4p - I put the whole 'read more' click into the var, like `var test = $('.ReadMore').on('click', function(event) {` I am sure that is not right, but not sure how to do it

Comment: just put the function not the binding. and set test at the right place

Comment: Sorry I am not very good with JQuery / Javascript - I am not sure what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have, as Su4p said, put the Handler in a var, not the whole binding  (which would return only the jQuery Object of the given Selector). 
So you have to replace

```
var test = $('.ReadMore').on('click', function(event) { .......
```

with

```
var test = function(event){...}
$('.ReadMore').on('click', test)
```

Additional, make sure that you define test, or whatever you will call your handler var in the end, in a scope, where it'll be accessible by the calls. The best way to go is to capsulate everything in a var itself, reserve the scope of the function, e.q. with

```
var self = this;
```

direct int the start, so you can later access every var & function by the scope prefix "self."
Something like:

```
var MyNamespace = function(){
    var self = this;
    this.validCommentRequest = false;
    this.CommentRequest = {done : false};
        // Your clickhandler, named 'test' before
    this.clickHandler = function(event){
        self.CommentRequest = $.ajax({
            // your request here
            success : function (data){
                self.validCommentRequest = true;
            }
        })
    }


    $('.ReadMore').on('click', self.clickHandler);

    $.when(self.CommentRequest).done(function() {
        if(!self.validCommentRequest)return;
        if ($('.FeedBackCommentFull').is(':visible')) {
            $('.ReadMore').off('click', self.clickHandler);
            console.log( 'test...off' );
        }

        $(' .CloseComment ').click(function() {
            $('.FeedBackCommentFull').slideToggle(700,"easeOutBounce");
            $('.ReadMore').on('click', self.clickHandler);
            console.log( 'test...on' );
        });
    }); //End of When       
}
```

I hope this gives you a little idea how you could structure your code. The nice sideeffect of this is also not to pollute the global namespace.

Comment: that you, I was trying to get my head around JQuery / JavaScript scope, which I have never completely understood. Thanks, I try this.

Comment: I can recommend you 'The secrets of the javascript ninja', a whole chapter there covers only the scope system of javascript

Comment: I would have commented only a little code sample after the last comment, to underline your comment. It wasn't my idea to steal from you, i just haven't enough reputation to comment. For the same reason, i can't do any upvote

Comment: Thanks I will look into that, but I am trying to get my head around this and with my code, I put the ajax code within the on click function call, so the ajax would fire when the button is click, but here you have taken it outside, and it does not seem to load anything, I will update my question above with my new code.

Comment: I haven't read the entire answers and looked for proper logic and stuff, but i would suggest nulling the 'self' variable at the end of the method to prevent possible memory leak

Comment: I have update my answer as well, so the ajax request belongs in the click handler. The commentRequest is initialized as a plain object, only with the attribute "done" as false, so it doesn't fail te jquery when construct (or at least, it shouldn't). Also, i directly binded the click handler, so it should work

Comment: @xanobius, I have updated my code with your updated answer, and I got the following error   `Cannot set property 'CommentRequest' of undefined`

Comment: Could you update your post according to your changes? There are still severall errors in structur: 1. You have to initialice CommentRequest like i did, before you can use it with "self." 2. You still save the jQuery object and not only the function in your handler Variable 3. Your Ajax request is outside the Handler function.

Comment: Aye, that was my fault. I wasn't familiar with the $.when function, and my workaround couldn't work. Note the new "validCommentRequest" wich i build in, to trick it another way, maybe it helps you. A little hint: If you add 'dataType : 'json' ' to your ajax-call definition, you jQuery does the parsing directly for you, and you don't need to do it yourself with $.parseJSON(reply); you directly receive a js-object as reply

Comment: @xanobius - sorry got busy with work, I have added your changes to the code, but still the same, `Cannot set property 'validCommentRequest' of undefined` - I have updated my question with what I did, I have not change the JSON datatype let but I will do when I know its working.

Comment: This seems a lot more hard to do, than the on/off example used on the JQuery website. That example does not seem to even talk about scope, but then I take it; that is because I am using AJAX and doing more complex progress - What I might do, is just remove the button or overlay an div tag with no click event on it. That does seem to be the easy method